# Modeling a house, issue with roof

Tags: modeling

So I'm modeling a house, and the issue is, I have a garage coming out of it, but the roof wont blend correctly. I was wondering if anyone knows how I might do this.[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "*wont blend correctly*". It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried flashing along the joints between the two roofs?  A textured plane folded to match the intersecting tiles?
 Pic link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjplaglo3gpp6gu/Flashing.png?dl=0  (Click in a vacant space to clear the gaff)

Comment: If you're having trouble joining the two roofs I've dropped a short video for you here - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/570tllhsdnfrcaw/FlashFM.mp4?dl=0

(It's too big to place with an answer)